# Helicon ISAPI Rewrite proxy not forwarding requests

Tags: proxy, isapi-rewrite

I have the following rules defined in my helicon file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^current.mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule /reg http://another.mydomain.com/registration [NC, P]
```

When I navigate to the URL http://current.mydomain.com/reg I just receive a blank page. It doesn't seem to be that Helicon is forwarding the request to the other site. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

try using the following istead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^current\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^reg http://another.mydomain.com/registration [NC,P]
```